# Using pictures as links in MooTool's "Floom" script?

Tags: javascript, html, mootools

Is there any way in floom to load a specific webpage when a user clicks on an image?

---

The normal syntax is:

```
var slides = [
            {
                image: 'image-url.jpg',
                caption: 'loriem ispum'
            }
```

---

I would like to be able to do something like this.

```
var slides = [
            {
                image: 'nature-photo0.jpg',
                caption: 'loriem ispum'
                link: 'http://www.google.com'
            }
```

---

This way that when my user's click on the images they will be directed to the url.

Comment: yes, if you actually post the source code / jsfidle example, I am sure it can be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the author of Floom.

The script provides a `onSlideChange` event which can be utilized to achieve this.

First inject the slideshow into a `a`, then use `onSlideChange` (the first argument is the single image object) now just update the `a` with the correct link:

```
onSlideChange: function(slide){
    link.set('href', slide.link);
}
```

This should work.